# python plot multiple line time serie

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a matplotlib plot with timestamp on the X axis and the score on abscisse Y, and the represent the evolution of score of an id in the time.

```
id  timestamp   score
1   1           100
1   2           115
1   3           120
2   2           12
2   2           20
2   3           15
2   4           30
3   1           14
3   2           100
5   2          20
6   3          20
7   4         100
```

for example the id=1, should be represented by a line in the graph and represent the the evolution of its score in the time,

same case for other id. (the number of id is unknown, I got them from large csv file).

I'm trying several plot but no solution.

How may I create a plot with multiple Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

id        = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,5,6,7])
timestamp = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,2,3,4])
score     = np.array([100,115,120,12,20,15,30,14,100,20,20,100]) 

pl.figure()
for i in np.unique(id):     # Loop over all the unique id's
    pw = np.where(id == i)  # which elements belong to this id
    pl.plot(timestamp[pw], score[pw], '-x', label=str(i))
pl.legend(frameon=False, loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you very much, I will apply your algorithm on my csv data. thank you